# ActiveAdmin limiting has_many association retrieval?

Tags: activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi this is my first spin with active admin, I have the two models:

1. Patient
2. Attributes

Where a **Patient has_many Attributes**

I created a patient resource like this:

`rails g active_admin:resource patient`

It seemed to work fine, however: the query active admin is creating:

```
Patient Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "patient".* FROM "patient" ORDER BY "patient"."id" desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
Attribute Load (1878.2ms)  SELECT "attributes".* FROM "attributes"
```

The problem is with the second one, because I have about 200 000 Attributes so SELECT * "attributes" is killing my computer.

I've been looking for an hour on how to limit the second query. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out why the query tried to select all of the attributes.

ActiveAdmin tries to create a filter area, by default and retrieves all possibilities for the belongs_to association in order to create a drop down.

To get around this I wrote a custom filter which excludes the attribute like:

```
filter :name
```